# List of tuples of 2 elements using a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I want to use a list comprehension to initialize a list of tuples that has a 2 elements in it, my attempt is as follows:

```
SIZE = 10
possible_positions = [(x, y) for x, y in range(0, SIZE)]
```

But that gives me an error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

What is the right way to do it ? I know I can use a for loop, but I want to know anyway.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` return a single value per iteration, you should use `zip` combined with `range` in the following way:

```
zip(range(SIZE), range(SIZE))
```

Using `zip` will also save you the trouble of creating the list of tuples so calling `list(zip(range(SIZE), range(SIZE)))` will give you the end result